# Update field-level security using APEX

Tags: apex, field-level-security

Can an apex code perform an bulk update on a field-level security to `visible`

I have moved few objects and each objects has almost dozens of fields and its very time consuming to go on each field and click on `Set Field-Level Security` and check on `Visible`, I'm looking a way to achieve the same functionality by using Apex class. Is that possible?

Comment: Abu, I came across somewhat similar kind of question in developers forum a few months ago. I haven't tried, but might be helpful for you. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AY54IAG

Comment: i have looked at it before posting the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other way I found seems much less clicks is  by going to:

```
Manage Users ==> Profiles ==> {click on profile name} ==> Go To 
>> Custom Field-Level Security ==> {find your custom object and click on View }
```

When you click on View it will open a window in it you will find all your fields list, Click Edit to Visible.

This is much better then going through each individual field and click `Set Field-Level Security` etc... too many clicks in the approach I was doing but the above approach is better you have all the fields.

Comment: for those using hti sanswer , the path has changed slightly... manage users -> profiles -> <select whatever profile> -> object settings -> <select whatever object>